# How to json response according to search params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, getjson

I want to get json response according to filters. Now on page load I'm getting json response for the every properties which are listed in that page.

In the same page I have filters, so if I search property through filters according to that json response should change.

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:city].present?
       @properties=Property.where("properties.city = ? ",params[:city],"%#{params[:city]}%")
    elsif params[:cityname].present?
       @properties=Property.where("properties.city = ? ",params[:cityname])
    else
      @properties = Property.where("properties.status = ?", '1')
    end
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @properties.as_json(only: [:id, :latitude, :longitude]) }
      end
  end
end
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you clarify what response from controller do you expect and what you're getting right now?

Comment: @Esse, Now  i'm getting json response for all properties which are present in the view page by the above code on page load(this is ok ). but after that i am searching property through filters(for eg: according to city), at this time i need only json response of (id, :latitude, :longitude) for properties which are in that city only. but i'm getting json (id, :latitude, :longitude) for every properties in that page